# Reference rewriterule matched group in a rewritecond regex?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using Apache's mod_rewrite module. Is there a way to reference a group captured by `RewriteRule` within the regex of `RewriteCond`?

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*(?=/#How can I 'paste' $1 = RewriteRule's (.*) group here?#$))
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE_PATH:%1]
```

Here I will match the base path of the request URI, for example, if I request `mysite.domain/subdir/my/site/dir`, and `.htaccess` is inside `subdir/` then:

```
1) RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ----> ^(my/site/dir)$ -----> $1 = my/site/dir
2) RewriteCond /subdir/my/site/dir ^(.*(?=/#I need to 'paste' the $1 RewriteRule's matched group here#$))
```

How can I do that so that my RewriteCond regex is generated 'dynamically' and becomes:

> ^(.*(?=/**my/site/dir**$))

Where **my/site/dir** is what was matched in RewriteRule's $1 group?

Comment: ok your description is confusing because you're trying explaining how you think it  should work. Can you just explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to be more concise and clear. When the RewriteRule matches, its captured group is stored in $1 and is available in `RewriteCond` pattern string as `$1`. So if `RewriteCond` is `$1-%{REQUEST_URI} ([^-]*)-(.*?)\1$`, `$1-%{REQUEST_URI}` will expand to `my/site/dir-/subdir/my/site/dir-/subdir/my/site/dir`. I need to do the same, but expand inside the regular expression of `RewriteCond`, not the string against it matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question, but here is a way to get the  RewriteBase dyanmically

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1-%{REQUEST_URI} ([^-]*)-(.*?)\1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%2]
```

Your RewriteBase path is now available for use in the env %{ENV:BASE}

Comment: Can I use `$1` of `RewriteCond $1-%{REQUEST_URI}` within `([^-]*)-(.*?)\1$` and have it expand to its content before performing the match?

Comment: No, thats not allowed in the condition pattern, however you could use **\1** for the first capture group in rewrite cond.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that was what I was trying to understand.